# Jquery setInterval execute on page load

Tags: jquery

Helllo, I have a function that needs to be executed every 10 seconds. It works like this:

```
setInterval(function () {

}, 10000);
```

The problem is that I need this function to be executed once on page load - now the first execution happens only after 10 seconds. Is it possible to do what I want with setInterval, or is there another function?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Name the function and call it in both places.

Comment: You've been given answers that suggest using setInterval or setTimeout. setInterval is easier to manage should you want to cancel the repetition.

Comment: @popnoodles They can both be cancelled in a similar manner; it's just a matter of keeping the last interval or timeout "handle" and clearing it when necessary.

Comment: Similar but setInterval is one handle that doesn't get changed on each iteration so there's less work to do to keep track of it.

Comment: @popnoodles It doesn't matter whether the handle changes, because the same variable would get updated and so by the time you want to clear the timer, there's no perceived difference.

Comment: Ok let's say for some reason you wanted to store that handle's value in data() on an element using jQuery so that you could have several different elements that won't ever interfere with each other's intervals. Instead of setting the data just once, it would need updating every iteration, adding to the work done by js.

Comment: @popnoodles Surely that "work" is not a major deal in most cases; if performance is truly an issue, using `setInterval()` will maybe shave  off a few microseconds :)

Comment: every shavable microsecond is worth shaving.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the most obvious way:

```
var myFunction = function() {

};

myFunction();
setInterval(myFunction, 10000);
```

Alternatively, use `setTimeout()`:

```
(function foo() {
    // do stuff here
    setTimeout(foo, 10000);
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

There may be a better way, but this will work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var readyNow = 0;

    //Runs immediately, waiting ten secs before setting flag to true
    setTimeout(function(){
       readyNow++;
    },10000);

    //Starts immediately, but flag won't be true for first ten seconds
    setInterval(function () {
        if (readyNow==1) {
            //do your code
        }
    }, 10000);

}); //END document.ready()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var fnc=function(){
        /* do your stuff here */
        setTimeout(fnc, 1000);
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){
        fnc();
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to name the function which you want to execute like:

```
function myFunction() {

}

setInterval(myFunction, 10000);
```

Here is myFunction the function that is executed every 10 seconds. The call on the last line